# HMRC Tax Returns for following year

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, estimated-taxes

If my startup business is running at a loss after adding costs of supplies and money come in, how would this affect income tax in the following year?

As any gains in the following year would need to repay the business deficit, does the minus figure get carried over into the following tax year?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it would as **you** pay income tax not your company.

If you decided to pay your self less salary or changed the way you handled staff pensions vial salary sacrifice for example - this could effect both your tax bill and the companies.